# Find MIN price/row in MySQL

Tags: mysql

First time here and it possible this has been covered before. My question is suppose you have this table:

```
guid    provider    cc     variable   name             units    unit_cost
1       1           509    T          Haiti Variable   1        0.3
2       2           509    T          Haiti Variable   1        0.27
3       2           84     F          Vietnam 5        1        1.2
4       2           84     F          Vietnam 10       1        2.4
5       1           84     F          Vietnam 5        1        1.1
```

I am trying to write a query that will give me the least costs for all "names" for a given "cc"

I need the output to be:

```
provider          cc       name      unit_cost
1                 84       Vietnam 5      1.1
2                 84       Vietnam 10     2.4
```

I have tried using min and group by but either i get all provider 1 or I get all records or I get 1 record (the min of the unit_cost)

The idea is to get all "names" and unit_costs fro a given "cc" regardless of the provider

thanks in advance

Comment: Regardless of your experience level, you should always post your code and indicate what research you've already done. As your question is written right now, you could find the answer by reading the documentation. With more detail, it may be more clear to us what you're struggling with.

Answer (score 0):

Use order by desc and limit to solve your problem